# What is basic package structure in the project for Java?

Tags: java, spring, package

I'm trying to learn some basics of Java and Spring. Recently I came across some beginner project and one of the first steps was to create a Spring Initializr thanks to its website, where everything is clear to me. The next step was to create a basic package structure in the project: model, controller, repository, config, service.

Could someone explain me what exactly is meant by creating these packages after creating a new project? I tried to look up the information myself, but unfortunately I couldn't find an answer anywhere.

Comment: Do you know about Java packages and their meaning in a technical sense?

Answer (score 0):

I will start by recommending reading about [Packages in Java](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/package/packages.html).

In a nutshell, packages are folders. They are used for storing (mainly) classes, but other entities can be stored in packages as well. For example, text files, pictures, etc. In Java, there is no hard set rule that state that only classes must be stored in packages. That said, this is typically not the way projects are structured.

One of the most important functions of packages is to provide namespace for classes. Consider two classes named `Table`. One is a table containing data and the other is a table used to put stuff on top of; for example a dining table. This means that `Table` will have to different meanings. Operating Systems will not allow for two files with the same name to exist in the same folder. Therefore, you need to put them in two folders (packages). In the code, you can break ambiguity by declaring the objects using the class' fully-qualified name. For example,

```
myproject.furniture.Table diningTable = new myproject.furniture.Table();
myproject.data.Table dataTable = new myproject.data.Table dataTable();
```

There is also access protection with packages by using default access modifier (no modifier). For example:

```
package myproject

class PackagePrivateClass {
    // class contents omitted
}
```

Notice that this class is not `public`. In Java, this means that ***this class is visible to other classes in the same package only***. Not even classes in sub-packages will have access.

In summary, packages provide namespace, physical organization, and access protection.

The second thing you should be familiarized with is the best practices with regards to naming your packages. Organizations tend to have packages structured with the domain first, then the main system the code is part of, then subsystems, etc. Before providing examples, here is an article about [Package Naming](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/package/namingpkgs.html) from Oracle.

- *java.awt* => Contains all of the classes for creating user interfaces and for painting graphics and images. AWT stands for *Abstract Window Toolkit*

When you see the package name, it gives developers and idea what type of classes can be found inside. This will help looking for functions when you are not familiarized with the API (which in turn will help you learning the API much faster). Imagine how hard would be to learn Java if all classes were in the same folder. Imagine how hard will be to figure out what the project does if meaningful names are not used. In the example above, it is kind of easy to figure how what to expect out of classes in the *java.awt* package.

I was hoping to give you more examples, but I am out of time. Maybe later I will return and write more about this.

Answer (score -2):

Package is nothing but a group of classes. You want to categorize your classes basis their respective purposes. If it's just for self-learning, your package structure should be like

```
org.novak.sample.service.*
```

This package should contain all Services, not anything else.

Comment: This is not correct. Packages are not _group of classes_. Packages are folders. And, even if you could argue that folder keep "group of classes", there are more than that. There are access rules pertaining to packages. Also, you fail to explain what each dot-separated part is supposed to represent.